# How to left align the text shown in the following figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I am stuck in between and I need to left-aligned the text **Suraj Prakash Sharma**, **Email**,**GitHub**,**LinkedIn**.

See the following figure, you can see space which I marked with a red box. I want to remove that space so that in the document the text become left aligned.

[image: Document Image]

Below is the Latex code for generating the above document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.75in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.75in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\hypersetup{
    % bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat's toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat's menu?
    pdffitwindow=true,      % page fit to window when opened
    pdftitle={CV - Suraj Prakash Sharma},    % title
    pdfauthor={Suraj},     % author
    pdfsubject={Resume},   % subject of the document
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=magenta,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue           % color of external links
}

% Margines

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.215in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.2in}

\definecolor{titleColor}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%% vertical space %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{l  p{8cm}  p{8cm}}
     &
     \begin{itemize}
     \setlength\itemsep{.01em}
        \item[] \textbf{\Large Suraj Prakash Sharma}
        % \item[] \textbf{Bachelor of Technology in Computer Science Engineering}
        % \item[] \textbf{NIIT University Rajasthan, India}
        \item[] \textbf{Email: }
        \item [] \textbf{GitHub: }
        % \item[] \textbf{Skype ID: }
        \item[] \textbf{LinkedIn: }
    \end{itemize}
     &
     \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{.01em}
        \item[] \textbf{\large NIIT University, Rajasthan}
        \item[] \textbf{Bachelor of Technology}
        \item[] \textbf{Computer Science \& Engineering}
        \item[] \textbf{Phone: }
    \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{table}
  \vspace{-.8cm}

\begin{tabularx}{.98\textwidth}{llp{2cm}lll}
    \hline
    \textbf{Examination} & \textbf{Specialization} & & \textbf{University / Board} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{CPI}\\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
  \end{document}
```

Can anyone walk me out of this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why are you using a floating environment (`\begin{table} ... \end{table}`)? Why are you centering the `tabular`? If you want two columns that span the whole page make sure, that the combined length equals `\textwidth`

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `amssymb` package, there can be no good reason, let alone excuse, for loading the archaic `latexsym` package. A separate comment: Since you're using the `geometry` package to set most of the page and text block parameters, it's inconsistent (and poor practice) to then fiddle with the low-level parameters `\oddsidemargin` and `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particular problem you point out can be resolved using

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5.8cm}  p{10cm}}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
```

[image]

However, you are better off using just `tabular` as in the second MWE below which yields:

[image]

You can increase `\arraystretch` if you want more space between lines.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5.8cm}  p{10cm}}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
 \setlength\itemsep{.01em}
    \item[] \textbf{\Large Suraj Prakash Sharma}
    \item[] \textbf{Email: }
    \item[] \textbf{GitHub: }
    \item[] \textbf{LinkedIn: }
\end{itemize}
 &
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
    \setlength\itemsep{.01em}
    \item[] \textbf{\large NIIT University, Rajasthan}
    \item[] \textbf{Bachelor of Technology}
    \item[] \textbf{Computer Science \& Engineering}
    \item[] \textbf{Phone: }
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{\Large Suraj Prakash Sharma} \\
    \textbf{Email: }  \\
    \textbf{GitHub: } \\
    \textbf{LinkedIn: } \\
\end{tabular}%
\hfill%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{\large NIIT University, Rajasthan} \\
    \textbf{Bachelor of Technology} \\
    \textbf{Computer Science \& Engineering} \\
    \textbf{Phone: } \\
\end{tabular}%
}%
\end{document}
```